# How can i reportprogress to a backgroundworker multiple times?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a small class

```
public class MyProgress
        {
            public string Report1 { get; set; }
            public string Report2 { get; set; }
        }
```

Then in a method i want to report in real time each filename:

```
private void DirSearch(string root, string filesExtension,string textToSearch)
        {
            List<MyProgress> prog = new List<MyProgress>();
            string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(root, filesExtension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
            {
                int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
                if (var == 1)
                {
                    string filename = filePaths[i];
                    prog.Add(new MyProgress { Report1 = filename });
                }
            }
            backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, prog);
        }
```

Not sure if the ReportProgress should be out the FOR loop or inside after the prog.Add line.

And then in the progresschanged event

```
private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (p in (e.UserState as List<MyProgress>))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Progress for {0} is {1}", p.);
    }              
}
```

I'm getting errors in the foreach i'm not sure what type should be the variable 'p'

I tried:

```
foreach (List<MyProgress> p in (e.UserState as List<MyProgress>))
```

But getting error:

Error   8   Cannot convert type 'Search_Text_In_Files.Form1.MyProgress' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Comment: But you are pass a string (filename) and trying to cast it so List ?

Comment: @Paparazzi: He's also passing just a strong from inside the loop. He's reporting progress once as it happens, and once as a summary when the worker loop is done, passing different data structures.

Comment: @EricJ. Agree.  I answered the error and figured (hoped) OP would figure it out.

Comment: I made a mistake the string was for testing but i want multiple so i changed my question the type i want to pass is MyProgress List not string.

Comment: Come on man that is a moving target and makes the existing answers invalid.  Why in the world would you use ReportProgress when it is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP totally changed the question
you don't know what p should be?
hint you are enumerating a List of MyProgress

```
foreach (var p in (e.UserState as List<MyProgress>))
```

but you are passing a string

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, filename);

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.UserState.ToString());           
}
```

and this is the typical signature of a do work
even if DirSearch is the working method you should be passing BackgroundWorker to it IMHO
and you should pass your results out as .Result - prog

```
    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {   
        // Get the BackgroundWorker that raised this event.
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Assign the result of the computation
        // to the Result property of the DoWorkEventArgs
        // object. This is will be available to the 
        // RunWorkerCompleted eventhandler.
        e.Result = ComputeFibonacci((int)e.Argument, worker, e);
    }
```

Comment: Ok i will try to figure it out. In my Dowork event i'm calling the DirSearch method.

Comment: I figured out in progresschanged: List<MyProgress> mypro = e.UserState as List<MyProgress>; and then i'm using the mypro first index: ListViewCostumControl.lvnf.Items.Add(mypro[0].Report1); and it's working.

Comment: Just follow the documentation.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  Referring to global type variables is not a good practice

Answer (score 0):

> Not sure if the ReportProgress should be out the FOR loop or inside after the prog

You want to report progress from inside your `for` loop that is doing the work. If you pass a list of progress reports in a single call to ReportProgress, backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged will be invoked just once at the end of your processing. All of your progress reports could come at once, when all the work is done.

Your current code reports progress as it is being made, and attempts to report it again after everything is done. You pass different data types into the same progress report handler, `string` and `List<MyProgress>`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.Length; i++)
{
    int var = File.ReadAllText(filePaths[i]).Contains(textToSearch) ? 1 : 0;
    if (var == 1)
    {
        string filename = filePaths[i];
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(0, filename);
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Progress for {0} is {1}", e.UserState);
}
```